# Neo4J: Speeding up MATCH using indexes

Tags: neo4j

I've got nodes like this:

```
(a:label1 {id:'a'})-[r:rel {id:'1']->(target:label2)
```

***Note**: I have an INDEX on `a.id`. Also, the `r.id` coming from `(a)` is unique to `(a)`.*

However, when I try to `MATCH (a:label1 {id:'a'})-[r:rel {id:'1'}]->(target:label2) RETURN target`, the query is slow, even though I have an index on `a.id`.

Is there any way I can speed up this MATCH query?

---

The only thing I can think of is to add an index property to (target) like `(target:label2 {index:'a:1'}`. This should speed up the match, but I don't want to duplicate data for the sake of speeding up match queries if I don't have to.

Comment: If you don't use labels, it will not make use of indexes. Use labels !!!!!!! Secondly inspect the query plan ;-)

Comment: I am using labels in this instance, I just wanted to create terse example code. Will edit the question now to reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: Seconding using PROFILE on your query to look at what it's doing, and adding that (after expanding all nodes in the profile output) to your description. You want to see NodeIndexSeek. You do NOT want to see NodeByLabelScan. The [Query Tuning](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-tuning) section of the developer docs may help you here.